# Angular2 run animation on leave & observable filter

Tags: angular, animation, angular2-template

I have a component that I can animate on entry like this, the entry animation works fine. The handleRemoval method gets executed and an event emitter filters the component from the list of components (using observables). But the :leave animation does not run:

```
    @Component({
        animations: [
            trigger(
            'enterAnimation', [
                transition(':enter', [
                style({transform: 'translateY(100%)', opacity: 0}),
                animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1}))
                ]),
                transition(':leave', [
                style({transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1}),
                animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateY(100%)', opacity: 0}))
                ])
            ]
            )
        ],
        template: `
            <div class="mb1 card text-xs-center rounded" [@enterAnimation]="show">
```

...

```
export class ContentPropertyComponent {

    show: boolean = false;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.show = true;
     }

    handleRemoval(contentProperty: PropertyModel) {
        this.show = false;
        this.delete.emit(this.contentProperty);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide something to understand it? It is not understandable. we need to see how you use emit and what happens behind the scene?

Comment: can you add a plnkr or other [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the help - I ended up solving the issue - the problem was the way I was removing the contentProperty object on the container

Answer (score 1):

Angular introduced the `:enter` and `:leave` shortcuts in version `2.1.0`, so if you're using an earlier version (as I suspect), you should use the `void => *` and `* => void` transition definitions. Or, alternatively, upgrade your Angular distribution to `2.1.0+`.

Changing your code accordingly works in Angular 2.0+

```
animations: [
    trigger("enterAnimation", [
      transition('void => *', [
          style({transform: 'translateY(100%)', opacity: 0}),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1}))
        ]),
        transition('* => void', [
          style({transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1}),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateY(100%)', opacity: 0}))
        ])
    ])
  ]
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/xW38PWgD3SQyhRv09IUW?p=preview

Comment: Clearly the OP meets these requirements or the `:enter` transition wouldn't be working. Maybe the reason your demo works is because it doesn't incorporate observables.